# Java Json Repeating the key

Tags: java, json

I have a problem always i call the method addplayers he inserts into the jsonfile the array required, but, he always create new key , so, i'm trying to insert a new player in the key Players always i create a new player.
I created some conditions for that but is not working, like parsing the file and check the key.

the **expecteded result**:

```html
{
    "players": [
        {
            "current_Energy": 100,
            "level": 1,
            "name": "tenente",
            "experiencePoints": 0,
            "team": "Giants"
        },
        {
            "current_Energy": 100,
            "level": 1,
            "name": "tenente",
            "experiencePoints": 0,
            "team": "Giants"
        },
        {
            "current_Energy": 100,
            "level": 1,
            "name": "tenente",
            "experiencePoints": 0,
            "team": "Giants"
        }
    ]
}
```

**the result at moment:**

```html
{
    "players": [
        {
            "current_Energy": 100,
            "level": 1,
            "name": "tenente",
            "experiencePoints": 0,
            "team": "Giants"
        },
        {
            "current_Energy": 100,
            "level": 1,
            "name": "tenente",
            "experiencePoints": 0,
            "team": "Giants"
        },
        {
            "current_Energy": 100,
            "level": 1,
            "name": "tenente",
            "experiencePoints": 0,
            "team": "Giants"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "players": [
        {
            "current_Energy": 100,
            "level": 1,
            "name": "tenente",
            "experiencePoints": 0,
            "team": "Giants"
        },
        {
            "current_Energy": 100,
            "level": 1,
            "name": "tenente",
            "experiencePoints": 0,
            "team": "Giants"
        },
        {
            "current_Energy": 100,
            "level": 1,
            "name": "tenente",
            "experiencePoints": 0,
            "team": "Giants"
        }
    ]
}
```

**The Method**

```
 public void addPlayer(PlayerManager playerManager) {
    if (file.exists()) {
        System.out.println("FODASEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE");
        try {
            PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("data.json",true));
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            JSONArray jsonArray;
            ArrayUnorderedList<Players> dataplayer = playerManager.getPlayersList();

            try {
                jsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(new FileReader(file));
                jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("players");
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // Caso não exista, cria um novo objeto JSON com a chave "players"
                jsonArray = new JSONArray();
            }
            Set<String> keys = new HashSet<>();
            if (jsonObject.containsKey("players")) {
                keys.add("players");
            }

            if (!keys.contains("players")) {
                jsonArray = new JSONArray();
                jsonObject.put("players", jsonArray);
            } else {
                jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("players");
            }

            for (Players player : dataplayer) {
                JSONObject playerObject = new JSONObject();
                playerObject.put("name", player.getName());
                playerObject.put("team", player.getTeam().toString());
                playerObject.put("level", player.getLevel());
                playerObject.put("experiencePoints", player.getExperiencePoints());
                playerObject.put("current_Energy", player.getCurrentEnergy());
                jsonArray.add(playerObject);
            }


            printStream.println(jsonObject);
            printStream.flush();
            printStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

At a glance the problem seems to be that you're reading and changing the same file, which you have open in append mode:

```
PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("data.json",true));
```

The `true` parameter there means whatever you write on that file will be appended at the end when you write to it, which seems compatible with the behaviour you're seeing.

Depending on what you need to achieve, you might prefer to just write on a different file as output.

Comment: i used the true parameter because if i take it off he will reset the file , if i have 2 players and i want input one new player he loses the other 2

Comment: Yes but what you're doing here is that you read the players from the file, add the new player and then write the modified JSON object on the same file.

From what I gather, what you should be doing is the following:
1) Read the whole file once and keep the FULL JSON Object in memory
2) Add the new player to the JSON Object (IE: add it to players collection object)
3) Write the new, modified JSON Object in a (new) file, erasing the previous one.

I'd also suggest considering using something like the Jackson library unless you have specific reasons not to.